# stripping input causing null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, palindrome

I am trying to create a method that strips a string of whitespace and punctuation to check if it is a palindrome.  When filling a char array of stripped chars I get a null pointer exception.  To me it makes perfect sense, i am filling the array of the same length with only letters or numbers.  if there are leftover chars then i fill them with a space (later to be stripped with trim).  Without char[] strippedInput = null; i get variable may not have been initialized.  With it I get null pointer exception.  I drew a simple diagram of what would happen to the stripped array when I input "if, then." and everything seemed to match up.  There seemed to be a value for each array index of strippedInput yet netbeans is telling me that something is null.

```
    static boolean palindromeCheckC(String inputString)
    {
        boolean isPalin2 = false;

        char[] inChars = inputString.toCharArray();

        char[] strippedInput = null;

        int offsetIndex = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
        {
            if ((Character.isLetter(inChars[i]) || Character.isDigit(inChars[i]
                )) == true)
            {
                strippedInput[i-offsetIndex] = inChars[i];
            }
            else offsetIndex++;
        }
        for (int i = inputString.length()- offsetIndex; i < inputString.length(); i++)
        {
            strippedInput[i] = ' ';
        }
        System.out.println(strippedInput);

        //to string
        //reverse
        //compare to    if 0 => isPalin2 = true


        return isPalin2;
     }
```

Comment: You don't initialize `strippedInput`...

Comment: Post that `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You need to create the array before you start setting its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that instead of initializing your array, you set it to null.  Try changing:

```
char[] strippedInput = null;
```

to

```
 char[] strippedInput = new char[inputString.length()];
```

I understand that the `strippedInput` will likely contain fewer characters than are in the `inputString`.  However, as far as I know, it is possible that you will need the same amount of characters in the stripped array.  If you do not need all of them, just write a null character at the end the data and it will work/print correctly.  Regardless, this will solve your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The `strippedInput` is not supposed to be of the same `length` as the `inputString`.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu True, but he needs to allocate it to prevent NPE.  It is possible he would need all the characters.  If he doesn't, he can still null terminate the array and it will print the result just fine.